# How to change the pixel color of an image in real time

Tags: android, colors, drawing, pixel

I need to develop a function that changes the pixel color of an image in real time, I currently wrote this part of the code that seems to work partially

```
private void changePixelsColor() {
        try {
        tileView.buildDrawingCache(true);
        tileView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        int height = tileView.getDrawingCache().getHeight();
        int width = tileView.getDrawingCache().getWidth();
        int[] pixelNumber = new int[height * width];

        tileView.getDrawingCache().getPixels(pixelNumber, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        for (int i = 0; i < pixelNumber.length; i++) {
            if (String.valueOf(pixelNumber[i]).length() > 2) {
                String hexColor = "#" + Integer.toHexString(pixelNumber[i]).substring(2);
                if (hexColor.compareToIgnoreCase("#f0f1f0") == 0) {
                    pixelNumber[i] = Color.RED;
                }
            }
        }

        tileView.getDrawingCache().setPixels(pixelNumber, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        File file = new File(MYPATH);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        Bitmap mappedCar = Bitmap.createBitmap(tileView.getDrawingCache());
        mappedCar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        mappedCar.recycle();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        tileView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        tileView.destroyDrawingCache();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }       
}
```

Specifically I'm using a "TileView" library to show the user an image (I'm simplifying the explanation), in a certain part of the code I need to scan all the pixels of an image, and replace some (eg # f0f1f0 with the red).

Currently I can retrieve the pixel map and understand for each of them what color it is. What I can not do is change the image colors in real time and save the result in a file.

/*********************EDIT 1 *********************/

[image]

Comment: I checked my code with the debugger and hexcolor takes that color, 
the for loop works, what comes after no

Comment: dont use image cache - if it is an `ImageView` use the source `Bitmap` and set its pixels

Comment: The problem is that I'm using a "TileView" that is a custom component: https://github.com/moagrius/TileView

Comment: so you are lucky then - you have all the sources, so you can modify that library as you wish - see `Tile.java` sources